# Bootstrap Modal only shows top border

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage with multiple modals.  For this issue, I am opening one modal, the user is entering some data, a query is being ran, and the displays are shown in a grid (this modal is closed).  Then for each row returned there is a Select button that will open a new modal populated with the data from this row.  The issue is that this second modal is not displaying.  There is a thin bar that looks like the border of the modal, and the background does fade like the modal is displaying.  Also, if I click this select button before running the query, the modal works fine.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="service-code-details" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h2 id="myModalLabel">Service Code Details</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>some content</p>
            <input type="text" name="Id" id="Id" value=""/>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--button-->
<a  data-id="12345" title="Add this item" class="open-ServiceCodeDetails btn" href="#service-code-details">Select</a>


$(document).on("click", ".open-ServiceCodeDetails", function () {
 var Id = $(this).data('id');
 $(".modal-body #Id").val( Id );
 $("#service-code-details").modal('show');
});
```

Comment: why do you have modal-body nested inside of a modal-body?

Comment: Also make sure that the html for the 2nd modal is not nested in the first modal.